# Prove a set of polynomials factorized in products of first degree polinynomials is a basis of the polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I apologize if the title isn't good, I didn't know how to well sumarize the problem in one sentence.

The problem is this:
Given $n$ different real numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$, we define: $$f_1=(x-a_2) \ldots (x-a_n) \\ f_2=(x-a_1)(x-a_3)\ldots(x-a_n) \\ \vdots \\f_n=(x-a_1)\ldots(x-a_{n-1})$$
Now we have to prove that $\lbrace f_1, \ldots, f_n \rbrace$ is a basis of of the vector space of all polynomials (with real coeficients) of degree less or equal than $n-1$.

I've tried expanding those $f_i$ when $n=2, n=3, n=4$ and $n=5$ and i've got a non-good looking pattern, explicitly it looks like this when $n=k$: $$f_1=x^{k-1} - (a_2+ \ldots +a_k)x^{k-2} +(a_2a_3+\ldots+a_2a_n+a_3a_4+\ldots+a_3a_n+\ldots+a_{n-1}a_n)x^{k-3} - a_2 \ldots a_n $$ In general for $f_i$ the expresion is the same just that the missing term is $a_i$ instead of $a_1$. Sincerely I have no idea on how should I proceed and I don't know if that expansion is somehow useful. Any help will be very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that they are linearly independent:

If there are $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n \in \Bbb R$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i = 0$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. Use this fact for each $a_i$ to get $\alpha_i = 0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Ok, I think i got it, thanks. But i can't still prove that i can write any polynomial as linear combination of those

Answer (score 0):

Hint: this is rescaled [Lagrange basis polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that information, it seems quite advanced for me